# Finite fields and primitive elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb F_9$ be a finite field of size $9$ obtained via the irreducible polynomial $x^2 + 1$ over the base field $\mathbb F_3$.

1. How can you find a primitive element?
2. Make a list of the elements of $\mathbb F_9$ together with a primitive element and all the powers of the primitive element.

Comment: I think there is confusion between the answers ; do you mean primitive element in the *field-theoretic sense* (i.e. $\mathbb F_9 = \mathbb F_3(\theta)$) or in the *group-theoretic sense* (i.e. $\mathbb F_9^{\times} = \langle \theta \rangle = \{ \theta^j \, | \, 0 \le j \le 7 \}$).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: In the context of **finite** fields a primitive element is a generator of the multiplicative group. This is standard FF speak. Unfortunately it is a bit at odds with the rest of field theory. If you haven't seen it before, there is no way to know about the varying practices, so don't feel bad!

Comment: @Jyrki: What does "FF speak" mean?

Comment: I guess it stands for Finite Field speak.. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I assume that you are looking for a generator of $F^*$. You can just go through all the $8$ elements of $F^*=\{1,-1,x,x+1,x-1,-x,-x+1,-x-1\}$ and compute their multiplicative orders. But with a little bit of thought you can avoid most of these computations. The following method is also applicable in other finite fields. We have the Frobenius automorphism $a \mapsto a^3$. Remark that $a$ is a generator iff the order is $8$ iff $a^4=-1$. This already excludes $1,-1,x,-x$. So we should try $a=x+1$, and compute $a^3=x^3+1=x(-1)+1$, and $a^4=(-x+1)(x+1)=1-x^2=-1$. This shows that $x+1$ is a generator. The other generators are $x-1,-x+1,-x-1$.
2. Again you can do this easily with the help of the Frobenius.

Comment: Remark: This is not as elegant as Andreas Caranti's answer. The only advantage is that you don't have to know in advance that the group is cyclic.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, but where does frobenius  help finding the primitive element?

Comment: How is $1-x^2=-1$? Is it because $1-x^2=1+2x^2=1+2(-1)=1$ ? where $-1=2$ and $x^2=-1$

Answer (score 7):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f = x^2 + 1$. You see immediately that this has period $4$ in $F_9^*$, so $\alpha$ is not a primitive element. However you know that $F_9^*$ is cyclic of order $8$, and thus $\langle \alpha \rangle$ is the unique subgroup of order $4$.

So take any $\beta \notin \langle \alpha \rangle$, and this will be primitive. For instance, take $\beta = \alpha + 1$. In computing the powers, just use $\alpha^2 = -1$. (Of course you mean computing the powers in the form $c + d \beta = (c+1) + d \alpha$, for $c, d \in F_3$.)

You can also note that the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F_3$ is $g = (x -1)^2 + 1 = x^2 + x -1$, so that $\beta^2 + \beta - 1 = 0$. So you can use the relations $\beta^{i+2} = - \beta^{i+1} + \beta^{i}$ to quickly compute the powers of $\beta$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the *field-theoretic sense* :

You want to find an element $\theta$ such that $\mathbb F_9 = \mathbb F_3(\theta)$.

Since $x^2 = -1$, all the elements of $\mathbb F_9$ are 
$$
0,1,2, x,x+1,x+2, 2x,2x+1,2x+2
$$
and you multiply them together with the relation $x^2 +1 = 0$, or $x^2 = 2$. Since every element of $\mathbb F_9$ looks to be a linear polynomial in $x$... how about considering *any* of the last $6$ elements as primitive elements? If you need help understanding why they are primitive, ask.

Assuming the *group-theoretic sense* described in my comment for the question :

There is a theorem which tells you that $\mathbb F_9^{\times}$ is a cyclic group, and since $\mathbb Z / 8 \mathbb Z$ has $4$ possible generators under addition (namely $1,3,5,7$), you expect to possibly find $4$ generators of $\mathbb F_9^{\times}$.

$1$, $2$, $x$ and $2x$ obviously *don't* generate $\mathbb F_9$ because $2^2 = 1$ and $x^2 = 2$, so $\langle 2 \rangle = \{ 1, 2\} \neq \mathbb F_9^{\times}$, $\langle x \rangle = \{ 1, 2, x, 2x \rangle \} \neq \mathbb F_9^{\times}$ and $\langle 2x \rangle = \langle x \rangle$. Therefore, the other $4$ elements, namely $x+1,2x+1, x+2,2x+2$ must *all* be primitive, because they would correspond to $1,3,5$ and $7$ under an isomorphism $\mathbb F_9^{\times} \cong \mathbb Z / 8 \mathbb Z$ (isomorphisms preserve the order of the elements).

Compute the powers of say, $x+1$ as follows : $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 = 2 + 2x + 1 = 2x$ using the fact that $x^2 + 1 = 0$, hence $x^2 = 2$. Using your preceding calculations, $$
(x+1)^3 = (x+1)^2 (x+1) = (2x)(x+1) = 2x^2 + 2x = 2x+1,$$
and so on until you have all of them.

Hope that helps,

Comment: This is not correct, $x=i$ has multiplicative order $4$.

Comment: Yes, but it is still a primitive element, because $\mathbb F_9 = \mathbb F_3(x)$. Right? (by the way, no need to call this element $i$ just because it comes from $x^2 + 1 = 0$... might as well just call it $x$) That is the *definition* of being a primitive element. I don't need the element $x$ to generate the multiplicative group , I need it to generate the *field*.

Comment: Ok, you are right. It is a primitive element in the sense of field theory, but not in the sense of group theory. And the latter is meant here because of part 2.

Comment: I assumed it was in the field-theoretic sense, otherwise we would've asked for a generator of the multiplicative subgroup instead, which is cyclic for finite fields, and of course this is a different question.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg : I still think there is confusion... to be honest I've never seen the generator of the cyclic group be called "primitive element". The closest I've heard would be "primitive root" for the generator of the cyclic group of the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity in $\mathbb C$. Although this term seems to exist in "litterature" (if we can call wiki that) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_%28finite_field%29

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, concerning calling the Wikipedia "literature", Terence Tao and Tim Gowers use it routinely as a reference in their blogs, so I think we common mortals can do the same without any worries.

Comment: @Andreas : I wasn't concerned about quoting it, but more about calling it "literature" :P

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva,I see your point. IMVHO the only criterion for qualifying as literature is quality, and many (certainly not all) Wikipedia entries in Maths are certainly up to very high standards.

Comment: You can simplify the calculations by *not* replacing $-1$ with $2$.

Comment: @Martin : Personally I think of $F_3$ as $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, hence its elements are $0,1,2$ in my head and I think of $2^2 = 1$. This simplifies computations for me... it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ be the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $x^2+1$. You can show that $F$ is isomorphic to $F_3[A]$.

Comment: in the solution of the question F9 is defined as F9={a+bx:a,b in